# How to run bash from arbitrary build tasks in Visual Studio 2017 (directory-based project)?

Tags: bash, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to enable [custom build tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/develop-code-in-visual-studio-without-projects-or-solutions#enable-custom-build-tools) to use bash to build DocBook-based documentation in Visual Studio 2017. I use built-in Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows 10. I can launch cmd.exe and run `dir` as in MS's examples. However, I need to run `make ARGS` in bash and that's where I it fails with:

```
  '"bash"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

I can run cmd.exe interactively and start bash without any problems. But it fails in Visual Studio. Does VS2017 use some special environment? How to make it run bash via those tasks? I guess that I am missing something very simple and trivial, but I don't understand where to look at.

Essentially, I want to run `make all-html` command against the path with my DocBook sources.

Here is a minimal task example:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "Build all-html",
      "appliesTo": "*",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "bash"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the command doesn't naturally find `bash` like you would expect is because Visual Studio is a 32-bit program.  This means that it won't use the 64-bit cmd.exe when you specify commands.

You can reproduce what Visual Studio is doing by opening a 32-bit command window `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and trying the `bash` command from there.

The solution is to invoke `bash.exe` directly via the `C:\Windows\Sysnative` virtual folder.

You can find a discussion/explanation of the Sysnative folder and why it is necessary [here in the official Bash on Windows GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1598#issuecomment-272665234).

Here is an example command that should work for you:

```
{
  "taskName": "print-pwd",
  "appliesTo": "*",
  "type": "command",
  "command": "%WINDIR%\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",
  "args": [
    "-c",
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right from your link, the doc gives an example to list output using cmd: you should use `${env.COMSPEC}` to use `cmd.exe`, then gives `bash` as an argument.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "Build all-html",
      "appliesTo": "*",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "${env.COMSPEC}",
      "args": [
        "bash"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This run bash in interactive mode, but you can give bash commands with `bash -c` like this: `bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'`.

Note: this run bash at the root directory of your solution (you can check this with `bash -c 'echo $PWD'`).

Comment: I am also running Windows 64-bit, do you have a `COMSPEC` system env variable with `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` as value?

Comment: `%COMSPEC%` is `ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`